# How can I change the opacity of my text on hover?

Tags: css

On `hover` I would like the opacity of my image and text turn to 0.5. But it is working only with the image, not with the text:

```css
a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<a>
    <img src="http://agriculture.vic.gov.au/__data/assets/image/0005/182390/rabbit_img1.jpg" style="max-height:90px">
    <footer class="logo-footer">Matthew <cite>Rabbit</cite></footer>
</a>
```

Comment: You can add display: block; to anchor.

Comment: In Firefox and IE works fine, the problem is in Chrome (maybe in others webkit browser, I don't know) like @SkyWookie says with `display:block` the problem is solved, I found the same solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a>
    <img src="http://agriculture.vic.gov.au/__data/assets/image/0005/182390/rabbit_img1.jpg" style="max-height:90px">
    <footer class="logo-footer">Matthew <cite>Rabbit</cite></footer>
</a>

body {
  background: red;
}

a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor:pointer;
}

a:hover footer {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/djL0Lwbp/

Comment: Welcome. Glad I helped you. Cheers!